# How to show that an $\omega$-sequence is club in a limit ordinal $\gamma$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Suppose that $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal. We say that a subset $X \subseteq \gamma$ is *closed* if whenever $\delta < \gamma$ is a limit ordinal and $\sup(X \cap \delta) = \delta$, then $\delta \in X$. We say that $X \subseteq \gamma$ is *unbounded* if $\sup(X) = \gamma$. A set $X$ is *club* in $\gamma$ if $X$ is closed and unbounded in $\gamma$.

Now I am trying to show that if $\text{cf}(\gamma) = \omega$ (where $\text{cf}(\gamma)$ denotes the cofinality of $\gamma$), then any cofinal $\omega$-sequence is club in $\gamma$.

The text I am using has not skipped over cofinal sequences so am I correct to begin by letting $\langle \alpha_{\xi} \mid \xi < \omega \rangle$ be such that $\lim_{\xi \rightarrow \omega} \alpha_{\xi} = \gamma$ with the hopes of showing that this sequence is club in $\gamma$?

If so, I am unsure how to proceed from there. It seems pretty clear that the supremum over this sequence is equal to $\gamma$ and is therefore unbounded. The part I am having trouble with is how to show that it is closed. If I have some limit ordinal $\delta < \gamma$, I am unsure how to interpret the intersection of $\delta$ and this sequence. Do I need to show that for all $\xi < \omega$, if $\delta < \gamma$ and $\sup(\alpha_{\xi} \cap \delta) = \delta$ then $\delta$ belongs to this sequence?

Comment: $\sup(X \cap \delta) = \delta$ can never happen since X is an omega sequence, so its trivial.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that can never happen?

Comment: HINT: Any proper initial sub-sequence of an $\omega$-sequence is finite . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber while I agree with that statement, I don't see why that helps...

Comment: @Oiler Suppose $\delta<\gamma$. Then $X\cap \delta$ is a proper initial segment of $X$ (since $X$ is cofinal in $\gamma$). So $X\cap \delta$ is finite. Can you finish from here?

Comment: HINT: if $X\cap \delta$ is finite it has a largest element. What is the relationship between this element, and $\delta$ itself? What does that tell you about $\sup(X\cap\delta)$ versus $\delta$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber So assuming that you mean that $X$ is our sequence, $X \cup \delta$ is finite and therefore contained in our sequence? Also your last hint is confusing. By assumption we have that $\sup(X \cup \delta) = \delta$, correct? So I am unsure why that adds anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38937/discussion-between-oiler-and-noah-schweber).